# Python unittest patch mock entire class

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, patch

I have a class that I want to patch in my unittests.

```
class OriginalClass():
   def method_a():
     # do something
   
   def method_b():
     # do another thing
```

Now I created another class to patch it with, so the code for patching it is like

```
class MockClass(OriginalClass):
    def method_a():
        # This will override the original method and return custom response for testing.

patcher = patch('OriginalClass', new=MockClass)
mock_instance = patcher.start()
```

This works exactly as I want it to and I can return whatever responses required for my unittests.

Now this issue is when I want to verify that a method is called with the right parameters in the unittests.
I tried

```
mock_instance.method_a.assert_called_once()
```

But it fail with error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called_once'`.

How can I test the method calls here?

Comment: after `patcher.start()`, make a call first, `oc = OriginalClass()` and `oc.method()` then assert

Comment: That is what I'm doing inside the test itself, but when I try `assert_called_once` I get error  `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called_once'`

Answer (score 1):

I think `wraps` can be useful here:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

class Person:
    name = "Bob"
    def age(self):
        return 35

class Double(Person):
    def age(self):
        return 5


with patch('__main__.Person', wraps=Double()) as mock:
    print(mock.name)  # mocks data
    print(mock.age()) # runs real methods, but still spies their calls
    mock.age.assert_not_called()
```

Output:

```
<MagicMock name='Person.name' id='139815250247536'>
5
...
raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Expected 'age' to not have been called. Called 1 times.
Calls: [call()].
```

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called_once'.

Once mock object is created, there is no `method_a` exists, you have to call once `m.method_a()` before assert.

```
    m = mock.create_autospec(OriginalClass)
    m.method_a()
    m.method_a.assert_called_once()
```

> patch mock entire class

I took it as mock the whole class and all its methods, I would take an example from here
https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html

Applying the same patch to every test method, Here is my example, patch the entire Primary class as MockPrimay for every methods and every tests, `setup or SetupClass` could be added for the methods needed, even the whole class is mocked, but not every methods to be used in the tests.

```
from tests.lib.primary_secondary import Secondary


@mock.patch('tests.lib.primary_secondary.Primary')
class TestSecondaryMockPrimary(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_method_d(self, MockPrimary):
        
        MockPrimary().process()
        MockPrimary().process.return_value = 1
        oc = Secondary()
        self.assertEqual(oc.method_d(), 1)
        import tests
        self.assertIs(tests.lib.primary_secondary.Primary, MockPrimary)
```

The Primary is needed for the Secondary for this test

```
class Primary(object):

    def __init__(self, param):
        self._param = param

    def process(self):
        if self._param == 1:
            self._do_intermediate_process()
        self._do_process()


class Secondary(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.scl = Primary(1)

    def method_d(self):
        return self.scl.process
```

Comment: This will fix the issue of `assert_called_with` but I still need to return mutliple values from `method_a` based on the passed parameters.

Comment: @MahmoudAhmed, if u want to test method_a,  do not mock it. Mock it to test other methods or classes

Comment: Let me explain.

I have a class that calls an external service, I don't want to call this service in my tests.
So I mocked this class with another class. Every opration on my system involve calling multiple methods inside this class multiple times, so I need to return different response with different parameters.

I managed to achieve this with the above implementation. the issue is when I want to write a test to check that the system calls method with right parameters. I'm unable to call `assert_called_with` on these methods since these are real functions not a mock.